# Post a values with umlauts(äöü) to Cuba Portal App Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, encoding, urlencode, diacritics, cuba-platform

I have some with the binding in Spring MVC Controller (@ModelAttribute("name") String name)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authors", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String index(
        @ModelAttribute("name") String name) {...}
```

Post auf .../authors
Form data: name=Näöüme

In controller name:NÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼me

If i get the requests inputstream the name=N%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BCme is URLEncoded.

Is there a way to set the urlencoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to set the filterEncoding in web.xml:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: It seems that we (I am from CUBA Platform team) should add these settings to default template of portal. Thanks for investigation!